# MacOS: libvlc path for plugins in app package

Tags: macos, packaging, vlc, libvlc

My MacOS application uses the libVLC plugin for playback of a video file within the application window. libVLC is dynamically linked but when I try to get a new vlc instance with "libvlc_new" the following error is printed (and the variable intended to hold the pointer to the vlc instance is NULL):

> main libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.

I want to include the vlc plugins directly in the MySampleApp.app package. I tried to put them in different locations within the app package but libVLC does not find them.

Where do I have to store the vlc plugins / how can I tell libVLC where to look for the plugins?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

According to this [tutorial](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial_086c), on the videolan wiki, you supply arguments (like `argc`/`argv`) to `libvlc_new()` to define its behaviour.  One of them is `--plugin-path`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the current version (as threatened)

Comment: "as threatened"?  I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

In libVLC is stated:

> There is absolutely no warranty or promise of forward, backward and
>   cross-platform compatibility with regards to libvlc_new() arguments.
>   We recommend that you do not use them, other than when debugging.

therefore it would be good to offer one more answer to this question.

Plugin path can be set by setting VLC_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable:

```
setenv ("VLC_PLUGIN_PATH", path, 1);
```

I haven't found any way to do this through API.